# Changing Local Intranet security zone by registry

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-registry

I need to change the **User Authentication** options on the **Local Intranet** from the registry but couldn't determine the right value

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1]
"2001"=dword:00000000
"2004"=dword:00000000
@=""
"DisplayName"="Local intranet"
"PMDisplayName"="Local intranet [Protected Mode]"
"Description"="This zone contains all Web sites that are on your organization's intranet."
"Icon"="shell32.dll#0018"
"LowIcon"="inetcpl.cpl#005423"
"CurrentLevel"=dword:00000000
"1200"=dword:00010000
"1400"=dword:00000000
"2500"=dword:00000003
"Flags"=dword:000000db
```

I need to set the User Authentication to be : Prompt for username and password, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users this should do it:

```
"1A00"=dword:0x00010000
```